# Timeout issue while connecting to cloud SQL using Serverless VPC Connector, from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, connector, vpc

I am getting timeout issue while executing cloud function, which is connecting to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL), using serverless VPC Connector. I am using VPC connector, as the Cloud SQL has only Private IP.

Please find the details,

Cloud Function connections setting,

Ingress Setting - Allow all traffics

Egress Setting - Route all traffic through the VPC connector

Cloud Function code for the connection,

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "[USER NAME]",
                              password = "[PASSWORD]",
                              host = "[PRIVATE IP]",
                              port = "5432",
                              database = "[DB NAME]")
```

Comment: Does the Cloud SQL instance and the VPC Connector are in the same VPC (not the same subnet, the VPC!)?  What are  your firewall rules in your VPC?

Comment: Also please make sure you follow the next [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#configuring) to connect your Cloud Function to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Ys, Both the Cloud SQL instance and VPC connector are on the same VPC.

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors? Have you followed the Documentation I linked above? Could you also please see the logs from Stackdriver in order to see if they give some further information?

Comment: Could you please share the complete error log?